# onContextMenuClosed for class extending DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-contextmenu

I have a class extending a DialogFragment and in this I am showing a ListView. I want to have a LongPress option for the items in this list. So I have overridden `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected`. I have my context menu appearing with the correct options.

The issue I am having is that I can't call `getDialog().dismiss()` from within the `onContextItemSelected` method.

What is the proper way of closing a class extending DialogFragment, from within the `onContextItemSelected` method of the class extending DialogFragment?

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu, android.view.View, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)
 */
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    if(view.getId() == listView.getId())
    {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        Industry industry = (Industry) listView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);

        menu.setHeaderTitle(industry.name);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, USE_INDUSTRY, 0, USE_INDUSTRY_TEXT);
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if(item.getItemId() == USE_INDUSTRY)
    {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        Industry industry = (Industry) listView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);

        MyApplication.BUS.post(new IndustryEvent(industry.ID, -2));
        getDialog().dismiss();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have added the code as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer, `onContextItemSelected()` was not being called in my Dialog Fragment. Which meant that the `getDialog().dismiss()` was not being called.

The only way I can find around this is to set the `onMenuItemClickListener` for the MenuItem and register the click there. Below is the final code I am using.

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu, android.view.View, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)
 */
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    if(view.getId() == listView.getId() && isIndustryLevel)
    {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        Industry industry = (Industry) listView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);

        menu.setHeaderTitle(industry.name);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, USE_INDUSTRY, 0, USE_INDUSTRY_TEXT);
        menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnUseIndustryButtonClick());
    }
}

private class OnUseIndustryButtonClick implements MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener
{
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener#onMenuItemClick(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        Industry industry = app.industries.get(info.position);

        MyApplication.BUS.post(new IndustryEvent(industry.ID, -2));
        getDialog().dismiss();
        return true;
    }       
}
```